# Error Sending automation mail after registration using lotus script

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

**Question:**

**1. My question why after registration of an user still not listed in domino directory?**

**Case:**

1. I am using xPages form call lotus script agent.
2. All my script is using lotus script to register an user.
3. After Complete register an email, need to send automation notification mail to user as welcome mail.

when i complete registration, i want to send mail, it give me an error message:

*1.unable to deliver message 'ChunWH@devsvr1.pcs.com.my'*

*2.User 'ChunWH@devsvr1.pcs.com.my' not listed in Domino Directory*

[image]

**Register user Agent**

```
Option Public
Option Declare

Sub Initialize
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler


    Dim s As New NotesSession, db As NotesDatabase, a As NotesAgent
    Dim doc As NotesDocument
    Set db = s.Currentdatabase
    Set a = s.Currentagent
    Set doc = s.Documentcontext     '   uidoc 

    Dim maildoc As NotesDocument, body As NotesMIMEEntity
    Dim stream As NotesStream

    Dim groups
    groups = Null 

    groups = group(groups,"Everyone")

    Dim certid As String            '   full path of cert id
    Dim certpasswd As String
    Dim OU As String
    Dim lastname As String
    Dim firstname As String
    Dim middleinit As String
    Dim usrIdpath As String
    Dim mailsvr As String
    Dim mailfile As String
    Dim userpasswd As String
    Dim internetpathLength As String
    Dim internetpath As String
    Dim remapuserID As String

    Dim depvw As NotesView, depdoc As NotesDocument
    Set depvw = db.Getview("Department sort by dept")
    Set depdoc = depvw.Getdocumentbykey(doc.Dept(0), True)
    If Not depdoc Is Nothing Then
        certid = depdoc.IdPath(0)           
        certpasswd = depdoc.IdPassword(0)       
        OU = "" 
        lastname= doc.Name(0)           
        firstname = ""              
        middleinit = ""             
        usrIdpath = depdoc.DptIdStor(0) +doc.SelectMail(0)+ ".id"   

    '   remove "." replace with empty and remove the empty space
        remapuserID = remapChr(doc.SelectMail(0))   ' this is remapuserID

        mailsvr = depdoc.MailSvr(0)             '   mail svr

    '   Mail file name also cannot have . in between for example, mail/test1.apple, reason window not understand it 
        mailfile = depdoc.MailLocation(0)+ remapuserID          '   Mail\Person

        userpasswd= depdoc.UserPassword(0)                              
        internetpath = doc.SelectMail(0)+depdoc.InternetPath(0) '   mail address
        internetpathLength = Len(depdoc.InternetPath(0))    '   not used
    End If

    Dim reg As New NotesRegistration

    Dim dt As Variant
    dt = DateNumber(Year(Today)+1, Month(Today), Day(Today))

    reg.RegistrationServer = mailsvr        
    reg.CreateMailDb = True                 '
    reg.CertifierIDFile = certid            
    reg.Expiration = dt
    reg.IDType = ID_HIERARCHICAL
    reg.MinPasswordLength = 1 
    reg.IsNorthAmerican = True
    reg.OrgUnit = OU        
    reg.RegistrationLog = "log.nsf"
    reg.UpdateAddressBook = True
    reg.Storeidinaddressbook = false
    reg.MailInternetAddress =  internetpath 
    reg.Shortname=doc.SelectMail(0)     
    reg.Mailowneraccess =2          
    reg.Mailcreateftindex=True          
    reg.Mailaclmanager ="LocalDomainAdmins" 
    reg.Grouplist=groups            


    Call reg.RegisterNewUser(lastname, _    
    usridpath, _                
    mailsvr, _                  
    firstname, _                
    middleInit, _               
    certpasswd, _               
    "", _                                   
    "", _                                   
    mailfile, _             
    "", _                               
    userpasswd, _           
    NOTES_DESKTOP_CLIENT)              

    Dim acl As NotesACL
    Dim aclEntry As NotesACLEntry
    Dim dbUser As NotesDatabase
    Set dbUser = New NotesDatabase(mailsvr,mailfile)    '   mail/person.nsf
    Set acl = dbUser.aCL
    Set aclEntry = acl.Getentry( "LocalDomainAdmins" )
    If Not (aclEntry Is Nothing) Then
        aclEntry.UserType = ACLTYPE_PERSON_GROUP
        Call acl.Save()
    End if

'   call name nsf and open for edit for forcing user must change password first time
    Dim ndb As NotesDatabase  
    Dim viwUser As NotesView
    Dim docUser As NotesDocument
    Set ndb = New NotesDatabase( mailsvr, "names.nsf" )


    Set viwUser = ndb.GetView("People by Email")    
    Set docUser = viwUser.GetDocumentByKey(doc.SelectMail(0),True)
    Call docUser.ReplaceItemValue( "HTTPPasswordForceChange" , "1" )
    Print "Force user change password is updated"

    Call docUser.Save( True, True, True )   
    Print "Please wait ...... Registration in progress"

    Call doc.Replaceitemvalue("S_Process", "Pending")
    Call doc.Save(True, False)


    Dim agt As NotesAgent
    Set agt=db.getagent("(Welcome Mail)")
    Call agt.Runonserver()


EndOfRoutine:
    Exit Sub 'or exit function
ErrorHandler:
    Print Err & ", " & Error & " in line " & Erl
    Resume EndOfRoutine 
End Sub 
Function remapChr (oldString)
'   to replace all special character with a empty space after that trim to remove all special character in system
Dim oldChr, newChr, newString As String

oldChr = {! "" # $ % & ' ( ) * + , - . / : ; = > ? @ [ \ ] ^ _}
newChr = "                                                    {"

oldChr = Split(oldChr, " ")
newChr = Split(newChr, " ")

newString = Trim(Replace(LCase(oldString), oldChr, newChr))

remapChr = newString
End Function
Function group(groupArr, newReason$)
    If IsArray(groupArr) Then
        If groupArr(0) = "" Then
            groupArr(0) = newReason
        Else
            Dim counter%
            counter = UBound(groupArr) + 1
            ReDim Preserve groupArr(counter)
            groupArr(counter) = newReason
        End If
        group = groupArr
    Else
        Dim tempgroupArr() As String
        ReDim tempgroupArr(0)
        tempgroupArr(0) = newReason
        group = tempgroupArr
    End If
End Function
```

**Sending mail Agent**

```
Sub Initialize
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Print "Welcome Mail Agent started..."

'   This agent is a sub agent for register user, which let register agent call
    Dim s As New NotesSession, db As NotesDatabase, a As NotesAgent
    Dim doc As NotesDocument
    Set db = s.Currentdatabase
    Set a = s.Currentagent
    Set doc = s.Documentcontext     '   uidoc 

    Dim maildoc As NotesDocument, body As NotesMIMEEntity
    Dim stream As NotesStream

    Dim receiver$

    Dim tmpallve As NotesViewEntry
    Dim viwUser As NotesView
    Dim viwVe As NotesViewEntry
    Dim viwVc As NotesViewEntryCollection
    Dim docUser As NotesDocument

    Set viwUser = db.GetView("(Request sort by S_Process)") 
    'Set docUser = viwUser.GetDocumentByKey("Pending",True)
    Set viwVc = viwUser.Allentries


    If viwVc.Count = 0 Then          
        Print "No item found in this list"
        Exit Sub 
    End If

    Set viwVe = viwVc.Getfirstentry()


    Do While Not viwVe Is Nothing   '   loop to all entry
        Set docUser = viwVe.Document

        receiver$ = docUser.SelectMail(0) + "@devsvr1.pcs.com.my"
        '   send mail
        Set maildoc = db.Createdocument()
        Call maildoc.Replaceitemvalue("Form", "Memo")
        Call maildoc.Replaceitemvalue("Subject", "Welcome")
        Call maildoc.Replaceitemvalue("SendTo", receiver)
        Set body = maildoc.Createmimeentity

        s.Convertmime = False 
        Set stream = s.Createstream()
        stream.Writetext(|<html><body>|)

        stream.Writetext(|<p>Your application for registration ....</p>|)

        stream.Writetext(|<p>Welcome. Pleaase....</p>|)


        stream.Writetext(|<p><em>(No signature requried on this computer generated document)</em></p>|)
        stream.Writetext(|<p>*** This is a system generated email. | + _
        |Please do not reply to this email. ***</p>|)
        Call stream.Writetext(|</body></html>|)
        Call body.Setcontentfromtext(stream, "text/html;charset=UTF-8", 1725)
        Call maildoc.Send(False)
        s.Convertmime = True    

        Call docUser.Replaceitemvalue("S_Process", "Processed")
        Call docUser.Save(True, False)

        Set tmpallve = viwVc.Getnextentry(viwVe)
        Set viwVe = tmpallve
    Loop

    Print "Welcome Mail Agent finished..."


EndOfRoutine:
    Exit Sub 'or exit function
ErrorHandler:
    Print Err & ", " & Error & " in line " & Erl
    Resume EndOfRoutine 
End Sub
```

**new update of image on 25/09/2017**
 (after  set config router_debug=3 set config DebugRouterLookup=3 )

i try send manually will be fine...but using code directly send after registration will be fail. Not only that, i also try on sleep(2) , wait 2 second just send mail..it seem like my thought of not directly create mail account mail also not valid..not sure which part is wrong?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that your issue is one of time and caching. The Domino server maintains a Name Lookup Cache that only gets refreshed, well, occasionally (I have never figured out how occasionally that is but 5-10 minutes generally does the trick). This affects both the email functions and the web login functions. What I have done with my registration systems is have the agent that does the ID creation leave a document in it database that is in the status "Pending welcome email". Then another agent finds those docs and if they are more then 15 minutes old it attempts the email. if the email goes through then the status is changed to "Complete".

Note, you can reset the cache with the console command `show nlcache reset` and that almost always results in the user being able to get mail and login from a browser. But I have not been able to get that to work from a scheduled agent run on the server or a web agent.

Comment: let say i want to use "show nlcache reset" is it possible write in on the lotus script? If yes, may i know how to call that function in lotus script? If cant, i only can use the script to delay 10-15 minute to run welcome mail agent

Comment: Yup it related to times and caching...but my web agent not really success..if delay too long...my web browswer will tell me that is server time out. and the button of calling notes agent will be "stuck" on the page. ...so need some help on calling "show nlcache reset" script directly.

Comment: There is a NotesSession.Sendconsolecommand(server$, cmd$) that can be used, but that seems to require that it be run from a foreground preocess. Whenever I try it from an agent triggered from the web or a schedule it acts as a no-op. I'll admit I have not tried for several years though son you might have more success with new versions.

Comment: Thanks, with this 3 command solve the problem 

 Dim session As New NotesSession 
 Dim MyReturnValue As String 
 Dim MyReturnValue2 As String
 Dim MyReturnValue3 As String

 MyReturnValue = session.SendConsoleCommand(mailsvr, "tell router quit") 
 
 MyReturnValue2 = session.SendConsoleCommand(mailsvr, "load router")

 MyReturnValue3 = session.SendConsoleCommand(mailsvr, "Tell router update config")

Answer (score 0):

Can you take a look at the Person Document? See if that address is properly registered on the document.

You may also try to enable router_debug=3 and DebugRouterLookUp=3 and we may see where did it try to lookup the address.

Comment: It properly registered, but my Opinion is the process of "create mail file" might not immediately create during registered. else should be already in domino list. For Router_debug ...may i know where to enable it?

Comment: the error message would be different if the user's mail file is missing. You may also want to check if your Notes users can see that person on the address book. 

router_debug and DebugRouterLookup are notes.ini parameters.
go to the Domino Server Console and type in:

set config router_debug=3
set config  DebugRouterLookup=3

You may want to consult your Domino Server Administrator.

Comment: I agree. Try manually sending email to the user, either with the Notes client or by using telnet to connect to port 25 (see http://www.wikihow.com/Send-Email-Using-Telnet if you don't know the steps). This will verify that your messaging configuration is working on your dev server and that the mailbox is available. (And yes, I believe you are correct that the mailbox is not immediately available.That's going to make it hard to send your welcome message, but CBlunt is correct that it would be a different error if that was your current problem.)

Comment: i have already try set the router debug  and debug lookup.. i updated the image file on the question already.